# Asymptotic behavior of solution to differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've just started my first class in ODE's and I'm kind of stuck with the idea of asymptotic behavior.

The problem as is follows:
Find the general solution and use it to determine the asymptotic behavior for different values of a. $y(0) = a$ as $t\rightarrow$ $+\infty$.

$$y' - \frac{1}{2}y = 2\cos(t)$$

I've solved for the general solution:
$$y = \frac{4}{5}(2\sin(t)+\cos(t)) + Ce^{-t/2}$$

Where do I go from here? Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour is just sinusoidal—in particular, the $e^{-t/2}$ term vanishes as $t\to \infty$, while the remaining term does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The general solution actually appears to be $y=\frac{4}{5}(2\sin{t}-\cos{t})+Ce^{t/2}$, which I used but then copied OP's general solution when typing my answer. Sorry!

From my reading of the question, you want to determine the behavior of $y(t)$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$. Your general solution consists of two parts; the first:
$$
\frac{4}{5}(2\sin{t}-\cos{t})
$$
is periodic, and can be ignored in the long run once we consider the second:
$$
Ce^{t/2}
$$
which grows without bound. So, we can say that $y(t) \rightarrow +\infty$ when $C>0$, $y(t) \rightarrow -\infty$ when $C<0$, and its behavior is undefined when $C=0$. Now you just have to figure out what initial conditions $y(0)=a$ correspond to what values of $C$, which should be pretty simple. I hope I read your question correctly, and good luck in your ODE class!

Comment: Did you miss the minus sign?

Comment: Whoops, I solved the equation myself and ended up with a different equation, but I somehow typed in OP's equation when writing my answer. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: I'm guessing OP mistyped the equation. You'd need a decaying exponential for the question to make sense

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I understand this now. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you say that for $C=0$ the behavior is undefined ? We know its exact expression, which is that of a sinusoid.

Comment: @YvesDaoust We know that it is sinusoidal, but the question asks for the asymptotic behavior as $t \rightarrow +\infty$, and the limit of a sinusoid as it approaches infinity doesn't exist. I guess I'm being a bit literal about it though, and I'm sure any teacher will accept sinusoidal motion as well.

Comment: @ThatEvilChickenNextDoor: usually, asymptotic behavior is more than just converges/diverges.